# Защита ajax обработчика от частого обращения

Tags: ajax, php, безопасность, javascript

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) &&                 strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
```

После этих условий работаю с данными бд и отдаю их, js их выводит.
Проверка на ajax запросы.
Теперь нужно как-то защищать от частого обращения, обычные страницы защищаю так:

```
session_start();
session_save_path($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/log/session_comments");
if (isset($_SESSION[telecod_ip])) {
$time = ((int)(time() - $_SESSION[telecod_ip]));
if($time < 2) die("Нельзя обращаться к сайту чаще, чем 1 раз в две секунды!");
}
$_SESSION[telecod_ip] = time();
```

А вот прикрутить это к ajax проверке не получается, не понимаю, как.

Comment: На стороне клиента защита от слишком частых вызовов функции называется "debounce". Например, в underscore есть: [debounce](http://underscorejs.org/#debounce).

Comment: У вас, товарищ автор вопроса, логика страдает на самом примитивном уровне. Вы _не_ защищаете сайт от частого обращения, вы обрабатываете частые обращения настолько часто, насколько часто они поступают. Если вам кажется, что текст от session_start() до die выполняется не на вашем сервере, а в мозге Жанны Агузаровой, то ей и надо задавать такие вопросы. Фактическая разница тех ресурсов, которые вы не использовали, умерев с теми, которые были бы использованы, - микроскопическая. Основные ресурсы уже _все_ подняты, а вы бамц и помираете.

Answer (score 1):

Ладно, отвечу напрямую. Вы не можете в PHP запретить серверу обслуживать запросы, потому что сам PHP оживает, *после* того как сервер запрос принял и обработал и передал всю эту кучу данных в *скрипт* вместе со всеми подключенными модулями, PHP скомпилировал для вас все актуальные переменные (например, SERVER откуда берется?), короче, расположился в памяти сервера, заняв там нормально так места, и готов изготовить что потребуется...

Если бы все так было просто, как вы изобрели, такой напасти, как DDOS, не существовало бы.

Answer (score 0):

Через БД по ИП+информация о бразуере.

И странные у вас ограничения, зачем такие нужны? Ну, в любом случае дело ваше.

---

А если приспичило именно через сессии, то крутите в сторону Microsoft.XMLHTTP (я думаю, тут проблемка).

А для профилактики запустите через AJAX.

```
session_start(); 
print_r($_SESSION);
```

Если заработает, значит дальше, думаю, будет вам легче.